# Trying to use Objective C cocoa pod in Swift project, bridging file compiled as Swift code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I'm trying to use an objective C based cocoa pod (GCM) in a Swift based iOS project.  I have the cocoa pods installed and I've created a bridging file by hand, adding it to the build preferences as a bridging file.  The problem is that when I compile, the bridge.h file is compiled as Swift (when obviously it should be objective C).  More explicitly-  all of the lines inside the included.h files are throwing errors, not the bridg file itself.  Here's my bridge file

```
#ifndef bridge_h
#define bridge_h
#import <GoogleCloudMessaging.h>

#endif /* bridge_h */
```

Any idea what is going wrong and why the code being imported isn't treated as Objective C?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a coworker we figured it out-  the bridging file must include Foundation/Foundation.h and must do so before it includes anything else.  Otherwise it fails to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have the possibility to check and change your file type in the file inspector when you have your file selected. Look if it's objective-c header.

Comment: I thought about that, but it isn't actually an option.  Th only header option is C header (default, and what I'm using).  The objective-c options are source code and precompiled source code.  Neither of which works.